# Climbing up subsets of $\omega_1$ using reals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

*This is a bit of an odd question, so I've included the motivation below the fold.*

Throughout we work in ZFC+"$\omega_1^r$ is countable for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$:"

Say that a set $X\subset\omega_1$ is *really climbable* if $X$ is countable *(that's the silly case)* or there is some real $r$ and some $f\in L[r]$ such that for all countable $\alpha$, $$f(X\cap\alpha)\in X\setminus \alpha.$$ *(Note that we don't demand $f(X\cap \alpha)=\min(X\setminus\alpha)$.)* That is, an uncountable $X$ is really climbable if there is some real which lets us build a way to climb up $X$. Obviously sufficiently nice sets are really climbable, as are sets *containing* sufficiently nice sets; at the same time, under CH it's easy to build a non-really-climbable set. My question is:

> What can be said about the really climbable sets without CH?

In particular, it's not clear to me that "Every set is really climbable" is impossible.

---

Motivation: I'm trying to answer a question I left open in my thesis, which has been bothering me for some time *(which was also ultimately, but much directly, the motivation for [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278780/conflating-reals-and-sets-of-countable-ordinals-nicely) of mine)*:

For $K\subseteq\omega_1$, consider the game (on $\omega$) $Copy(K)$ where

- Player I builds a single linear order $A$
- Player II builds a list of linear orders $B_i$ ($i\in\omega$)
- Player II wins iff $(i)$ **every** $B_i$ is isomorphic to some $\alpha_i\in K$, and $(ii)$ if $A\cong\beta$ with $\beta\in K$, then $\beta=\alpha_i$ for some $i\in\omega$. *Here I conflate an ordinal $\gamma$ with the linear order $(\gamma, <)$.*

That is, player II is trying to "guess" what element of $K$ player I is playing; if player I can trick player II into building something not in $K$, they win, and otherwise they win if they build something not isomorphic to anything built by II. *(This is an instance of [a class of games defined by Montalban](https://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/papers/CopyableStructures.pdf).)*

By $\Sigma^1_1$-bounding, if $K$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$ then $Copy(K)$ can't be a win for player II, and it's easy to see that $Copy(K)$ *is* a win for II if $K$ is countable. And assuming CH, there is some $K$ such that $Copy(K)$ is undetermined. However, if we drop CH, then I don't know how to produce an undetermined $Copy(K)$, even using Choice - roughly, the reason is that we have continuum-many strategies to defeat but only $\omega_1$-many choices to make in building $K$ (and of course it's even consistent that there are as many strategies as there are subsets of $\omega_1$). "Obviously" there is still such a $K$, but the question is (so far as I know) open for now.

The question above is one which grows naturally out of this problem: intuitively, if it's consistent that every set of countable ordinals is really climbable, then it would be more plausible that "$Copy(K)$ is determined for all $K\subseteq\omega_1$" could be consistent with ZFC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Every set is really climbable": this contradicts AC. By AC construct a set $X\subseteq \omega_1$  such that $L[X]\models $"$\omega_1 =\omega_1^V$". Then  for arbitrarily large $\gamma < \omega_1$ we have that $L_\gamma[X\cap \gamma] \models $"*Every set is countable*". But such a set cannot be climbable, for if $f\in L[r]$ were a 'climbing' function, according to the definition we should have such $X\cap \gamma \in dom(f) \subset L[r]$ contradicting the inaccessibility of $\omega^V_1$ there.

On the other hand, assuming $AD$, for example in $L({R})$ assuming large cardinals (where also DC holds - but that is not relevant), by an early result of Solovay, every subset of $\omega_1$ is in some $L[r]$ for a real $r$; clearly then every such subset is really, and trivially, climbable.

Answer (score 3):

---

Concerning *Copy(K)*-determinacy: you mention that every set of countable ordinals being climbable would lend plausibility to this in ZFC (that is with AC).  We just saw that climbability fails under AC; of course $\forall K$*Copy(K)*-determinacy holds under AD; and if you make the game harder for II by insisting  (I make it that II has the winning strategy, not I, by Boundedness) that II's wellorders code all of $K$ below their supremum, then one can conclude that $K$ is in $L[\tau]$ where $\tau$ is II's strategy.  So for this slightly more rigorous game, its determinacy for all $K$ is inconsistent with choice and $\omega_1$ inaccessible to reals.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I don't see why II has the winning strategy. It seems to me that I still has a winning strategy, if it exists, by bounding.