# Undetermined copy/diagonalize games without CH

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, determinacy, infinite-games

*This question was the motivation behind [an earlier question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282621/climbing-up-subsets-of-omega-1-using-reals); having thought about it some more, that question seems nontrivial and the connection is actually pretty tenuous anyways, so I've decided to ask this directly:*

For $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\omega_1$, we let $G_{CD}(\mathcal{K})$ be the game defined as follows *(which is a special case of a broad class of games [defined by Montalban](https://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/papers/CopyableStructures.pdf))*: players $1$ and $2$ alternate building objects by finite extensions (with passing allowed) - in player $1$'s case, a single linear order $L^1$, and in player $2$'s case an array of linear orders $L^2_i$ ($i\in\omega$). Player $2$ wins iff $(i)$ each $L_i^2$ is in $\mathcal{K}$, and $(ii)$ if $L^1\in\mathcal{K}$ then $L^1\cong L^2_i$ for some $i\in\omega$. Put another way, player $1$ is trying to *either* build an element of $\mathcal{K}$ which player $2$ doesn't build, *or* trick player $2$ into building something not in $\mathcal{K}$.

If $\mathcal{K}$ is unbounded then $G_{CD}(\mathcal{K})$ can't be a win for player $2$ by $\Sigma^1_1$-bounding, and assuming CH it's easy to build an unbounded $\mathcal{K}$ such that $1$ doesn't have a winning strategy in $G_{CD}(\mathcal{K})$ either. However, in the absence of CH things seem much harder: intuitively, there are continuum-many strategies we need to defeat but only $\omega_1$-many "choices" involved in creating $\mathcal{K}$.

My question is:

> Does ZFC **alone** prove that there is some $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $G_{CD}(\mathcal{K})$ is undetermined?

"Obviously" the answer should be yes, but I don't see it immediately.

Comment: Maybe you can try to simulate a Gale-Stewart game as your game so you can get (in ZFC) an undetermination ? I'm thinking especially a game played on $2^{\omega\times\omega}$ since then you could encode countable ordinals at each step

Comment: @Max Remember the obstacle I mention in my question: whereas a general (Gale-Stewart) game is determined by continuum-many "atomic facts," these games are determined by merely $\omega_1$-many "atomic facts." There are fundamentally fewer CD-games than GS-games, in a precise sense, which gets in the way of any naive simulation attempt that I can see (which is of course the natural thing to try here); I've asked [a separate question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285651/undetermined-games-of-overdetermined-type) about this obstacle on its own.

Comment: I can prove that if player $1$ has a winning strategy, then $\mathcal{K}$ has an uncountable subset that when viewed/reinterpreted as a set of reals is $\mathbf{Σ^1_2}$.  Would that help?

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky I don't immediately see how, but it might. *(Can you sketch a proof? At the moment I don't see why it should be true, since player $1$ doesn't have to build an element of $\mathcal{K}$ to win.)*

Comment: We start with a winning player $1$ strategy and $ω$ elements of $\mathcal{K}$, and use that to find another element of $\mathcal{K}$, and then iterate.  If you like, I can give a full explanation (including how to get $\mathbf{Σ^1_2}$ complexity) as an answer.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky Oh yes I see, I was having a silly moment. That's nice - but I don't see how to use that fact.

Comment: Under CH, there is an uncountable $\mathcal{K}⊂ω_1$ without an uncountable $\mathbf{Σ^1_2}$ subset, but I do not know whether that is provable in just ZFC, or if there is a generic extension where it fails.

Comment: @DmytroTaranovsky Under CH there's an easier argument that there's an undetermined game of this type: just directly diagonalize against strategies.